# Jenkins Git pull request ${sha1}

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've configured Jenkins git pull request plugin according to docs: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin but build returns to me

`ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.`

If I leave "Branch Specifier" empty, Jenkinks goes through every PR (even closed) in my repo.
How to force it to build only open PR?

Comment: @Suirtimed, make sure your GitLab plugin and Jenkins versions are up-to-date

Comment: I'm not using the GitLab plugin and my Jenkins version is 1.596

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've set this up and is working perfectly. Here are my settings:
[image]

And the ghpr plugin settings is completely empty apart from these 2 fields

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry I haven't had a chance to dig back into this today, I've been building out pipelines...  I'll look tomorrow to see if this fixes it. Thanks!

Comment: I added the string parameter to default to "development" which is a branch in my repo.  That will allow me to trigger a build manually.  I'm still not getting builds triggered when I create a PR.

Comment: What kind of trigger are you using? I'm using github webhooks and those kick off the builds for me

Comment: I'd imagine a simple periodical '* * * * *' would do the trick too

Comment: I'd like to have a build triggered and executed when someone submits a PR on github.com like Travis-CI does.  As I have dug in deeper it seems that's not quite as straight forward as I had hoped.  Since @meza provided some screenshots and that led me to the answer, I'll go ahead and award credit since my question wasn't very clear :)

Comment: Thanks! :) What was the missing piece of the puzzle? For me it works like Travis, but it might have something to do with other settings I accidentally had. Would be nice to know what makes it tick!

Comment: Permissions issues mostly and not using Git Plugin to trigger the build on push, but just the PR Builder plugin.  Next I'll tackle the web hooks to trigger the build.